# Soon-to-be cultured milk with fresh fruit safe for consumption?

Tags: food-safety, fruit, milk, yogurt

Recently my cousin started to make yogurt. She told me that she puts diced, fresh fruit (strawberries, peaches) into the inoculated milk (pasteurized or sterilized, I don't know. <sup>1</sup>) and then let this set in the oven at ~50°C for some hours. After this, she puts the yogurt into the fridge. She makes enough yogurt for ten days; on the tenth day she takes the last yogurt portion and makes some new.

At the first thought I couldn't imagine that fresh fruits stay safe for ten days (I wouldn't eat cut fruits that stayed for ten days in the fridge!). But after some pondering I wondered if it's safe after all because the milk and the fruits are going to be cultured and undesired bacteria are going to be eliminated. I think freshly diced fruit only contain bacteria on the surface.

---

<sup>1</sup> I saw a really big jug of milk. She lives in Georgia, US. I don't know what's the common treatment of milk there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only are "friendly" bacteria being cultured, those bacteria make an acidic environment which is hostile to "bad" bacteria.

Myself, I make plain yogurt and mix things into it at the time of eating, but things mixed in from the start essentially become "yogurt-pickled" and should be fine for a reasonable period under refrigeration. A standard part of preparing to culture yogurt is a high-heat treatment (scalding) of the milk, both to kill off unwanted bacteria and to cause structural changes in the milk proteins that are beneficial to forming the yogurt curd.